# Appropriateness of question

Tags: discussion, questions

Is meta.stackoverflow.com the correct place to ask whether your question is appropriate for stackoverflow.com?

Is meta.stackoverflow.com even the appropriate avenue to ask whether meta.stackoverflow.com is the correct place to ask if your question is appropriate for stackoverflow.com?

If it is the appropriate avenue, should you reproduce your question in its entirety? If it is not, where can I ask this question, or should I simply ask the original question on SO and let the votes decide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct place to ask that. Such posts typically start out asking whether the topic of the potential question is appropriate for the site, but end up editing in a brief summary if the topic alone is not enough for us to help them figure it out (it's usually only enough if it is obviously off-topic).

I recommend asking following two criteria:

1. The question title mentions the topic (ex. "Are questions about Foo allowed on Stack Overflow?")
2. You boil your explanation of the potential down to the bare essentials to understand it's scope, subject, and what kind of answers it is looking for.