# Is meta an appropriate place to ask the question "should question X be moved to site Y?"

Tags: discussion, migration

There are several good questions in meta relating to what *types* of questions should be moved, say, from SE to CR.  However, is it appropriate to ask in meta about a specific question?  If I think question #123 might fit better on site XYZ, should I ask that in meta and help build a "body of precedent," or is such a specific question best left to the ephemera that is chat?

Related: [Appropriateness of question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152762/appropriateness-of-question)

Comment: Maybe on meta.meta.stackoverflow.com :p

Answer (score 3):

Whether question 123 might fit onto size XYZ is not the question you should be asking.  The question is, "Is question 123 **offtopic** where it currently sits?"  If the answer is "yes", *then* you can ask, "what site can we migrate it to, if any?"  If the answer is "no", then you leave it, because it's on topic.

Usually this discussion can take place on comments to the question, or simply through votes to close/migrate/reopen.  While you *can* bring it up on meta, it's usually only worth doing if there is a whole category of questions you're interested in, or if the discussion has gotten too heated or lengthy for the question's comments.

Comment: If the answer is "no" to the question of whether or not it's off topic *where it currently sits*.